# Centering text vertically with transition

Tags: html, css, css-transitions, flexbox

I'm using flex and transition to try and achieve something.

Never used flex before but thought it might work well with what I'm trying to achieve.

please see [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2qe5a9s1/)

What I'm trying to achieve is when you hover the box, the bottom bar covers the box (this works) and the title and text transition into the the centre of the box. This is half working.

They are centered horizontally but not vertically how I would like. The text should be closer together in the center.

Is this even possible or am I doing something wrong?

html

```
<a href="#" class="box-link row">
  <div class="overbox row">
    <h4>This is a title</h4>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, usu debet tation cu. Eam assum habemus dignissim ne</p>
  </div>    
</a>
```

css

```
.box-link {
    display: flex;
    flex: 1 1 0px;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    width: 19.8125rem;
    height: 19.8125rem;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    background:red;
    text-align: center;
    border:1px solid red;
}
.box-link .overbox {
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
    min-height: 15%;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0.9375rem;
    position: absolute;
    top: 85%;
    left: 0;
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
}
.box-link:hover .overbox {
    min-height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
h4 {
  margin:0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On hover, the text is aligned slightly right relative to the container because of a padding declaration.

For an illustration, remove `overflow: hidden` from the container element (`.box-link`).

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/2qe5a9s1/1/)

---

If you remove `padding: 0.9375rem` from `.overbox`, both boxes align and the text is perfectly centered horizontally.

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/2qe5a9s1/2/)

---

The reason the flex items are not centering vertically more closely is because on a multi-line flex container with `flex-direction: row`, flex alignment is controlled by the `align-content` property, not `align-items`. This is what you have:

```
.box-link .overbox {
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    ...
    ...
    ...
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
}
```

The property to use when there are multiple lines in the cross-axis is [`align-content`](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#align-content-property).

Add this to your CSS:

```
.box-link .overbox {
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    align-content: center;       /* NEW */
    ...
    ...
    ...
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
}
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/2qe5a9s1/4/)

---

*From the spec:*

> [**8.3. Cross-axis Alignment: the `align-items` and `align-self` properties**](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#align-items-property)
>
> `align-items` sets the default alignment for all of the flex container’s items, including anonymous flex items. `align-self` allows this default alignment to be overridden for individual flex items.
>
> [**8.4. Packing Flex Lines: the `align-content`
>   property**](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#align-content-property)
>
> The `align-content` property aligns a flex container’s lines within the
>   flex container when there is extra space in the cross-axis, similar to
>   how `justify-content` aligns individual items within the main-axis.
>   Note, this property has no effect on a single-line flex container.

Comment: Thank you for the help and the explanation..
just what i was after